# not execute on the terminal

Tags: command-line

Suppose That I saw these commands on the web

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

I copy all of them and I want to have them on my terminal. But the point is **I do not like execute them**. As you know If I select all three lines and copy all of them on the terminal, all of them will execute line by line. For for this moment I want to just have them on my terminal screen. and my self inter each line separately. So any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a subshell. Type `(` in your terminal, then copy the lines and close the statemant with `)`:

```
user@host:~$ (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator)
```

You can edit the commands in the terminal. As soon as you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the commands will be executed line by line. But don't forget the closing `)`.